# Drawing an activity

Tags: android, layout, android-activity

I need to create an activty that will show an information table. The problem is that I want to display the information like the following image. Each row has to be like:

[image: layout]

I dont really control the layouts yet... so if someone can guide me a little I would be really appreciated.

All of this has to be in code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds you you want to make a list with custom list items.

Typical approach would be to use a `ListView` with a custom adapter. You can derive an adapter from, say, `ArrayAdapter` and override its `getView`. There, you can use `LayoutInflater.inflate` to load an XML layout for the list item, and populate it with whatever data. If you really must do it "all in code", however, you can do things like `new RelativeLayout()` and `new TextView()` and add them to the parent view in this method. As for the layout itself, a `RelativeLayout` most likely works best to arrange everything.

[Here](http://goo.gl/1P9Q8) is an example of how it all fits together.